# When i run react-native app on emulator that time my Emulator is not shows proper screen and it will shows like below screen Please give me solution

Tags: android, windows, react-native, android-studio, android-emulator

When i start Emulator it is shows the black screen, But not proper Black screen it is shows dot dot screen many time
How can i solve this problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xvwW.png)

First i removed all data of android studio and react-native app but still this error occure.